# Dsiable Cache Abstraction from Code Based upon Some Configuration parameters

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-data

I am using Redis cache abstraction in my Spring boot application.
Going through many things i have come to one requirement , 
I want to make Caching enable or disable based upon some configuration.
following is the code where i use cache:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = IC_CACHE, key = "#id")
public IssueCategory getIssueCategoriesById(Integer id) {
    return issueCategoriesRepo.findById(id);
}
```

And here is how i configure it:

```
  @Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(@Value("${redis.host}") String redisHost,
        @Value("${redis.port}") Integer redisPort) {
    JedisConnectionFactory cf = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    cf.setHostName(redisHost);
    cf.setPort(redisPort);
   return cf;
}

@Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
RedisTemplate<Object,Object> redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate<Object,Object> template = new RedisTemplate<Object,Object>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(applicationContext.getBean(RedisConnectionFactory.class));
    return template;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new PieRedisCacheManager(
            (RedisTemplate<?, ?>) applicationContext.getBean("redisTemplate"));
    redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return redisCacheManager;
}
```

Say I have a variable in properties file which says :

```
rediscache=disable
```

Is there a way to disable cache at all based upon that configuration??

so that In the first code where i use `@cacheable`, code should directly get data from database

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can control the caching abstraction using a configuration. But it will be either completely enabled or completely disabled based on the configuration setting. Here is the code snippet to do the same. `NoOpCacheManager` is a way to disable cache even if you have `@Cacheable` parameters in your code.

```
@Value("${rediscache}")
private String isRedisCacheEnabled;

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    if(isRedisCacheEnabled) {
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new PieRedisCacheManager(
                (RedisTemplate<?, ?>) applicationContext.getBean("redisTemplate"));
        redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        return redisCacheManager;
    } else {
        NoOpCacheManager noopCacheManager = new NoOpCacheManager();
        return noopCacheManager;
    }
}
```